# pip выдаёт ошибку при попытке установки pyautogui

Tags: python, pip, pyautogui

Использую Windows 10 Домашняя, python 3.7, pip 20. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно можно сделать в данной ситуации: ввожу в командную строку, открытую от имени администратора: "pip install pyautogui", но вылезает ошибка:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\юзер\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\юзер\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\671D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpp8t5mfps'
         cwd: C:\Users\671D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gzj6zidv\pymsgbox
    Complete output (14 lines):
    running dist_info
    creating C:\Users\671D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-psy17f_c\PyMsgBox.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\671D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-psy17f_c\PyMsgBox.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\671D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-psy17f_c\PyMsgBox.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\671D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-psy17f_c\PyMsgBox.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\671D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-psy17f_c\PyMsgBox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\671D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-psy17f_c\PyMsgBox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 0: invalid start byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
    warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory 'pymsgbox'
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\671D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-psy17f_c\PyMsgBox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    creating 'C:\Users\671D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-psy17f_c\PyMsgBox.dist-info'
    error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\юзер\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\юзер\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\671D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpp8t5mfps' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Pillow и PyScreeze уже импортировала (как советовали другим людям, имеющих похожую проблему, но другую ошибку).

Comment: не уверен, но возможно проблема в этом `c:\users\юзер`, а именно в `юзер`. Попробуйте сменить имя пользователя на англ.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Правда, я создала нового пользователя, чтобы не рисковать с переименованием, но думаю, что Ваш совет тоже помог

Comment: комментатор выше кстати понял это по следующей строчке `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode`  - что говорит нам о проблеме с кодировкой, а такое обычно либо от кривой установки, либо от русских названий

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй скачать с сайт pypi pyarogui а потом введи команду pip install "адрес к файлу".whl